# How to identify the logged in user inside a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, users

I have a public registration form and a plugin which needs to create an entry for a user when that user is activated. That part works. Because I want to force an Admin to activate the user, I am using this code block to stop Craft automatically activating a user on registration:

```
public function init() {
    craft()->on('users.beforeActivateUser', function(Event $event){
        // stop the user from being able to activate their account. Forces admins to do so.
        $event->performAction = false;
    });
}
```

But this also stops an Admin from activating the user account via the control panel.

I can't work out how to test that the user performing the event is the admin and therefore skip that blocking code. I'd tried this:

```
public function init() {
    craft()->on('users.beforeActivateUser', function(Event $event){
        // stop the user from being able to activate their account. Forces admins to do so.
        if($event->params['user']->isInGroup('artists')){
            $event->performAction = false;
        }
    });
}
```

But that doesn't work, presumably because a new registering user doesn't belong to any group at the point that code is run.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question.

It sounds as though you want to check if the currently logged-in user is an Administrator, but it looks like you're actually checking whether the *newly-registered* user is an Administrator.

Here's how to [retrieve the currently logged-in User](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService#getUser-detail), and [check whether they belong](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/UserModel#isInGroup-detail) to a specific User Group.

```
function (Event $event)
{
    $user = craft()->userSession->getUser();

    if ($user && $user->isInGroup('groupHandle') {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could [check whether the current user has permission](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserPermissionsService#doesGroupHavePermission-detail) to perform a specific action:

```
if ($user && craft()->userPermissions->doesUserHavePermission($user->id, 'registerUsers')) {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Searching the class reference documentation, I see that the user is available from the [userSession service](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService) — but never tried this personally.

```
craft()->on('users.beforeActivateUser', function(Event $event){
    // stop the user from being able to activate their account. Forces admins to do so.
    if(!craft()->userSession->isAdmin()) {
        $event->performAction = false;
    }
});
```

or to just get the current user for other testing, `craft()->userSession->user`.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add to this thread...

Depending on which event you are listening to/watching for in your plugin, you might have to use a different approach to getting the user. For example, the `onActivateUser` event won't have a user's session to check just yet. But, you *do* have access to the event params...

**MyPlugin.php**

```
public function init() {
    ...

    craft()->on('users.onActivateUser', function (Event $event) {
        if (craft()->config->get('devMode')) {
        error_log('----- users.onActivateUser called -----');
    }

    // Get the user.
    $user = craft()->users->getUserById($event->params['user']->id);

    // Check for user group.
    if ($user && $user->isInGroup('groupHandle')) {
        // Do stuff..
    } else {
        // User does not belong to this group.
    }

    ...
}
```